# How to Concat Datetime without Losing Second Precision

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, concat

What is best way to Concat on datetime column with other fields, without losing/truncate millisecond precision?

Example: We have a column in datetime precision.

```
1988-02-27 00:00:04.000
```

We are creating rowhash on CONCAT

```
select hashbytes('SHA2_256',concat(SalesRecord,SalesDatetime))
```

The problem when doing Concat, we are losing second values.
You can test here,

```
create table dbo.SalesOrder
(
    SalesOrderId int primary key, 
    SalesRecord varchar(255), 
    SalesDatetime datetime
)
select concat(SalesRecord,SalesDateTime) from dbo.SalesOrder
select concat('ABC ',[SalesDateTime]) from dbo.SalesOrder

ABC Feb 27 1988 12:00AM
```

What is the optimal way to solve this?

Background: Rowhash was causing duplicates by removing seconds, pipe deliminator | not working either.

The following was not working:

```
declare @testdate datetime = '1988-02-27 00:00:04.000'
select concat('ABC',convert(binary(16),@testdate)) 
select concat('ABC',convert(varchar(25),@testdate))
```

Comment: great answers below, anyone know more optimal one; may not make difference between few rows, we will be conducting for millions, just curious, I am thinking its datetime2(3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the DATETIME value to a DATETIME2(3) before concatenating.

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT 
    CONCAT('ABC ', @now),
    CONCAT('ABC ', CONVERT(DATETIME2(3), @now));
```

Results:

```
ABC Oct 30 2018  3:01PM                      ABC 2018-10-30 15:01:30.617
```

Answer (score 2):

You are losing seconds because the default format for converting `datetime` to `string` is the same as:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(19), GETDATE(), 0);
```

Which outputs (for me, right now):

```
Oct 30 2018  2:02PM
```

You can try something more like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT
       (
         'ABC ', 
         CONVERT(char(19), GETDATE(), 25)
       );
```

Which outputs (again, for me, right now):

```
ABC 2018-10-30 14:02:55
```

If second aren't enough, just change `char(19)` to `char(23)`. If that's still not enough, you can consider changing that column to `datetime2` to get more precision.

Comment: @knightbob472 You have 10 `datetime` columns and this (along with other columns, like a unique primary key column) wasn't enough distinctness for row hashing? Do all 10 columns represent the same thing?

Comment: Well adding `.000` to both values won't really change the collision, need to fix the source so that granularity is actually there, but love to hear how you get on.